# Azure SQL Database sys.fn_get_audit_file or sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file troubles

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm having troubles on a Azure SQL Database where i'm trying to read DB Audit logs.

Both procedures sys.fn_get_audit_file or sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file sould be able to read a file.

But whatever I do i'm getting blank tables.But, even if I specify a non existing file I receive a table with zero records instead of a error.

So I'm afraid its something else.

My login is in the db_owner group.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you enabled auditing fro your Azure SQL database : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview?

Comment: Yes I did, I have the files on the Blob, but from the server I can't read them with these functions.

Comment: What is strange to me is that this function needs no extra authentication to be able to read the blob.

Comment: Could you please check if you can read audit records via Azure Porta(<database> -> Auditing -> View audit logs): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview#subheading-3

Comment: That was the first thing I did, yes there are records. I see the file increasing is size too.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I could only read XEL files by using the *same server* and *same database context* that they were created for. So for example, consider the following scenario:

- ServerA is the Azure Synapse instance I was creating the audit XEL files from, all related to DatabaseA
- ServerB is a normal SQL instance that I want to read the XEL files on

**Test 1:**
Using ServerB, try to read file directly from blob storage

Result: 0 rows returned, no error message

**Test 2:**
Using ServerB, download the XEL files locally, and try to read from the local copy

Result: 0 rows returned, no error message

**Test 3:**
Using ServerA, with the current DB = 'master', try to read file directly from blob storage

Result: 0 rows returned, no error message

**Test 4:**
Using ServerA, with the current DB = 'DatabaseA', try to read file directly from blob storage

Result: works perfectly

Because I really wanted to read the files from ServerB, I also tried doing a CREATE CREDENTIAL there that was able to read & write to my blob storage account. That didn't make any difference unfortunately - a repeat of Test 1 got the same result as before.